# Correct Logic for PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to produce an output like this:

```
{
  "properties": [
   {
     "name": "name",
     "value": "A company name"
   },
   {
     "name": "description",
     "value": "A company description"
    }
  ]
}
```

And i've written the logic as such:

```
$data = array(
    "properties" => array(
        "name" => "name", 
        "value" => $companyname,
        "name" => "address", 
        "value" => $AddressLine1,
        "name" => "address2", 
        "value" => $AddressLine2,
        "name" => "address3", 
        "value" => $AddressLine3,
        "name" => "locality", 
        "value" => $Locality,
        "name" => "city", 
        "value" => $Town,
        "name" => "state", 
        "value" => $County,
        "name" => "zip", 
        "value" => $PostCode,
        "name" => "country", 
        "value" => $Country,
        "name" => "phone", 
        "value" => $Telephone,
        "name" => "domain", 
        "value" => $Website,
        "name" => "lead_forensics_business_id", 
        "value" => $hubspotcompanyid
    )
);
```

Can someone highlight the correct way to produce the above output?

Comment: You're almost there. You just need to wrap each `name` and `value` pair with another array. `array("name" => "name", 
        "value" => $companyname),`, `array("name" => "address", 
        "value" => $AddressLine1),` ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `name` and `value` pair should be their own arrays. Like this:

```
$data = [
    "properties" => [
        [
            "name"  => "name", 
            "value" => $companyname,
        ],
        [
            "name"  => "address", 
            "value" => $AddressLine1,
        ],

        // And so on
    ]
];
```

(I've opted for the shorthand version of creating arrays `[]` instead of `array()` since it's, in my opinion, easier to read).

Comment: The output I get with the above places the second name/value array into 0 1 2 etc rather than in the properties array

Comment: @PaulAlmond - That should not be the case if you just do: `json_encode($data);`. Are you adding `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` when you json encode the data? If yes, remove it and you should get the result you want. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/Tt8Gc)

Comment: I'd missed the starting and ending brackets - this solution works thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick if i remember correctly:

```
$data = array(
  "properties" => array(
    array(
      "name" => "name",
      "value" => $companyname
    ),
    array(
      "name" => "address",
      "value" => $AddressLine1
    ),
    ...
  )
);
```

PHP automatically builds an {} or [] depending on the contents.
So u just use the `array()` function to build the entire structure.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ...

```
$data = array();
array_push($data, array('name' => 'name', 'value' => $companyname));
array_push($data, array('name' => 'address', 'value' => $AddressLine1));
array_push($data, array('name' => 'address2', 'value' => $AddressLine2));

$output = array();
$output['properties'] = $data;

echo json_encode($output);
```